# How to create a Project Template without requiring PacMan (or refresh)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, uwp, project-template

If you create a new Windows UWP project in VIsual Studio 2015 using the out-of-the-box Blank template you will find that intellisense works without having to build or refresh the project.

Now, create a custom project template based on the Blank template. You will find that your new project template creates a project fine. However, that new project does not have intellisense until PacMan (the Nuget package manager) fetches `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` from the package cache.

After you invoke PacMan and fetch `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`, your new project will still not have intellisense. That is, until you refresh your project in Solution Explorer. At that point, you are in business.

My question. What is the setting in the VsTemplate.xml that enables a custom project template to create a project and immediately work? That is to say, what can tell Visual Studio to go ahead and run PacMan and refresh the project?

There is one requirement to this scenario. It is important that this custom template not have a custom project wizard. That is not a viable solution to this problem. I believe this can be solved with configuration, not code.

> Please note, this question involves NuGet v3, not 2 or 1.

Does anyone know?